# Why Linux5.15 Arm64 `cpu_context_switch` set `sp_el0` to next task_struct base

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm64

I read the code below at `arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S` in Linux5.15

```
/*
 * Register switch for AArch64. The callee-saved registers need to be saved
 * and restored. On entry:
 *   x0 = previous task_struct (must be preserved across the switch)
 *   x1 = next task_struct
 * Previous and next are guaranteed not to be the same.
 *
 */
SYM_FUNC_START(cpu_switch_to)
    mov x10, #THREAD_CPU_CONTEXT // x10 = offsetof(struct task_struct, thread.cpu_context)
    add x8, x0, x10 // x8 = previous cpu_context address
    mov x9, sp 
    stp x19, x20, [x8], #16     // store callee-saved registers
    stp x21, x22, [x8], #16     
    stp x23, x24, [x8], #16
    stp x25, x26, [x8], #16
    stp x27, x28, [x8], #16
    stp x29, x9, [x8], #16  
    str lr, [x8]
    add x8, x1, x10 
    ldp x19, x20, [x8], #16     // restore callee-saved registers
    ldp x21, x22, [x8], #16
    ldp x23, x24, [x8], #16
    ldp x25, x26, [x8], #16
    ldp x27, x28, [x8], #16
    ldp x29, x9, [x8], #16 
    ldr lr, [x8] 
    mov sp, x9                     // <============================= confused
    msr sp_el0, x1                 // <============================= confused
    ptrauth_keys_install_kernel x1, x8, x9, x10
    scs_save x0 // save the scs_sp
    scs_load_current
    ret
SYM_FUNC_END(cpu_switch_to)
NOKPROBE(cpu_switch_to)
```

I feel confused about the assignments for `sp` and `sp_el0`(I ponited them in the code). In my mind, `sp` references to `sp_el1` when in kernel mode, so the code assigns a kenrel sp to `sp_el1` and a `task_struct` base address to `sp_el0`? I think when process switch happened, the `sp_el0` should be restored to the correcet user space stack top address, not a struct base ptr.

I know this is a design that use `sp_el0` to store the base of current `task_struct` base. But I think it happened just in the kernel mode. When `cpu_switch_to` happenes, the cpu will changed to user mode soonly. The `sp_el0` need to be restored to the correct user stack top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cpu_switch_to` is a kernel function, so all the registers during its operation are "normal kernel".

The idea with the function is that the processor begins executing the function while 'wearing' the context of a specific thread, but then returns 'wearing' the context of a different thread.

Every thread that is "waiting" has a kstack inside the this function, where the last time that the thread was executing "stopped".

### Regarding you first 'confused' line:

you can see that

```
mov sp, x9                     // <============================= confused
```

simply loads `x9` into `sp` - which came from

```
ldp x29, x9, [x8], #16
```

which came from the previous function call from -

```
mov x9, sp 
// ...
stp x29, x9, [x8], #16
```

`sp` is not special in any way, it's just another register.

### Regarding your second 'confused' line:

`current` points to your currently executing `struct task_struct`.

Under kernel 5.15, it is implemented in the following way:

```c
static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
{
    unsigned long sp_el0;

    asm ("mrs %0, sp_el0" : "=r" (sp_el0));

    return (struct task_struct *)sp_el0;
}

#define current get_current()
```

As you can see, it is vital to maintain that `sp_el0` keeps pointing to the *current* `struct task_struct` after a context switch.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, my previous misunderstanding was that there is only one kernel stack, not one kernel stack per process. `cpu_switch_to` function does the switching from one kernel thread to another kernel thread, not the switching of a process from kernel mode to user mode

Comment: @Thysrael yes, this is correct. there is a kernel stack per thread, and `cpu_switch_to` does in fact switch between one thread to another, and stays in kernel mode.